# No module named pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have been working on a program for a while now and never had this issue. I installed Kivy for a seperate program and then all of a sudden I get an error saying `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'` for my first program. I tried reinstalling it through CMD but it's already there.

```sh
C:\Users\xxxxx>python -m pip install pandas
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\xxxxx\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (0.25.3)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.6.1 in c:\users\xxxxx\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in c:\users\xxxxx\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from pandas) (1.16.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in c:\users\xxxxx\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from pandas) (2019.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\xxxxx\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.6.1->pandas) (1.12.0)
```

I also tried uninstalling it and reinstalling it but nothing worked, I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: can you "import pandas" from the python interpreter?

Answer (score 0):

Check if kivy is installed properly and if it runs in virtual environment (ve), if so you should install required packages in your ve directly.
See also kivy's installation guide:
https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html#installing-the-kivy-stable-release